# Hover div visible outside element

Tags: css

How can I keep the black box on hover, to be only visible sliding out inside the `box-1` div?

```css
.description {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: -100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}

.box-1:hover .description
{
    visibility: visible;

  bottom: 0;
}

.grid-item {
    background: rgba(6, 108, 121, 0.322);
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: grid;
    cursor: pointer;
    place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item box-1">
   <h2 class="consulting">Test</h2>
    <div class="description"><p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? Can't able to grasp the problem

Comment: When you hover the div.. it slides out from outside the div, instead of inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` to your parent

```css
.description {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: -100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box-1:hover .description {
  visibility: visible;
  bottom: 0;
}

.grid-item {
  background: rgba(6, 108, 121, 0.322);
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  cursor: pointer;
  place-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item box-1">
  <h2 class="consulting">Test</h2>
  <div class="description">
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the class `grid-item`

This will make the black box appear to slide from inside.

```css
.description {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: -100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}

.box-1:hover .description
{
    visibility: visible;

  bottom: 0;
}

.grid-item {
    background: rgba(6, 108, 121, 0.322);
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: grid;
    cursor: pointer;
    place-items: center;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item box-1">
   <h2 class="consulting">Test</h2>
    <div class="description"><p>Description</p>
</div>
```